# heroku push pg & sqlite3 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite

I have not idea how to fix this error. I've ran bundle install 1 million times. My gem file has the following code underneath and I am not deleting sqlite3 from my gem file:

```
    group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    end

    group :production do
    gem "pg"
    end
```

Error from server log:

```
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_5072a680-186f-45ae-bc1a-355f12885b46/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_5072a680-186f-45ae-bc1a-355f12885b46/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
   Installing rack-test 0.6.2
   Installing warden 1.2.3
   An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: It is most likely a problem with your database.yml file. Could you please post that file?

Comment: @Johnson Heroku ignores the database.yml so it can't be the problem.

@Kohl are you sure there isn't another `gem 'sqlite3'` somewhere in your gem file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
     Make sure to install PG on Heroku. If you have heroku toolbelt installed. Open the CMD.

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql
```

Make sure your gem file looks like this without white spaces:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Try to run bundle

bundle install --deployment

Comment: How does that fix the OP's problem? Please elaborate.

Comment: It worked for me, maybe there was an issue installing the posgresql add-on. That would make heroku use the rails default db... which is SQLite3.